# Why doesn't FindRoot work correctly?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I'm trying to find the roots of the following equation:

[image]

I need to find `λ`s for different values of `ξ`. I know that for all values of `ξ`, I must have `n<λ<n+1/2`. I use `FindRoot` to do this. When I put `ξ^2=2`, I can find all the correct roots. For example, for the first 5 roots, I have

```
FindRoot[x - Pi*Cot[Pi*x] == 0, {x, 0.5}]
(* Out[173]= {x -> 0.454288} *)

FindRoot[x - Pi*Cot[Pi*x] == 0, {x, 1.5}]
(* Out[174]= {x -> 1.36917} *)

FindRoot[x - Pi*Cot[Pi*x] == 0, {x, 2.5}]
(* Out[175]= {x -> 2.29891} *)

FindRoot[x - Pi*Cot[Pi*x] == 0, {x, 3.5}]
(* Out[176]= {x -> 3.24485} *)

FindRoot[x - Pi*Cot[Pi*x] == 0, {x, 4.5}]
(* Out[177]= {x -> 4.20427} *)
```

Comparing with the following plot, these roots are correct (The roots are where the red line is coinciding with the green curve):

[image]

But when I put some different value for `ξ^2`, for example `ξ^2=0.5` (which is a value which I need to use in my calculations), `FindRoot` doesn't give me the correct roots anymore:

```
FindRoot[x - 0.25*Pi*Cot[Pi*x] == 0, {x, 0.5}]
(* Out[191]= {x -> 0.362393} *)

FindRoot[x - 0.25*Pi*Cot[Pi*x] == 0, {x, 1.5}]
(* Out[192]= {x -> 1.18617} *)

FindRoot[x - 0.25*Pi*Cot[Pi*x] == 0, {x, 2.5}]
(* Out[193]= {x -> 2.11326} *)

FindRoot[x - 0.25*Pi*Cot[Pi*x] == 0, {x, 3.5}]
(* Out[194]= {x -> 2.11326} *)

FindRoot[x - 0.25*Pi*Cot[Pi*x] == 0, {x, 4.5}]
(* Out[195]= {x -> 3.07949} *)

FindRoot[x - 0.25*Pi*Cot[Pi*x] == 0, {x, 5.5}]
(* Out[196]= {x -> 5.04912} *)
```

Which are not the correct roots (specially the 4th and 5th ones) compared to this plot:

[image]

Why doesn't `FindRoot` work correctly? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's finding a root, which is all it is asked to do. Starting a bit closer might give the root that *you* want.  Try changing your .5 to x.1.

Comment: Indeed, put `x - 0.25*Pi*Cot[Pi*x] /.` in front of each `FindRoot` and you'll see it has found a correct root.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries, Thanks a lot for your answer. But I didn't understand what I should do. Where should I put `x - 0.25*Pi*Cot[Pi*x]`?

Comment: `x - 0.25*Pi*Cot[Pi*x]` is the expression that you want to set to zero for a certain x. `FindRoot` finds this x. If you now write `x - 0.25*Pi*Cot[Pi*x] /. FindRoot[...]` the found value of x is filled in in the expression and you see that it is indeed (close to) zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSolve` with a condition, instead. See:

```
    eq = x - (Pi/2)*0.5*Cot[Pi*x] == 0
    NSolve[{eq, 3.5 < x < 4.5}, x][[1]]
```

The output being

```
    {x -> 4.06081}
```

which correctly falls between 3.5 and 4.5.

Comment: This looks only good at the first glance because it doesn't find the root at 17.0059 when you use `16.5<x<17.5` and xi is `0.1`. On the other hand I have to admit, that `NSolve` finds most of the roots. I wonder whether one can instruct `FindRoot` to use the same method, because besically `NSolve` only knows the interval boundaries. The same is possible with `FindRoot` but it doesn't seem to work reliable with this.

Comment: But if you change the lower bound a bit, it gives the corretc result: `NSolve[{x - (Pi)*0.1*Cot[Pi*x] == 0, 16.4 < x < 17.5}, x]`, the output being `{x -> 17.0059}`.

Comment: The problem is, that you maybe don't want to fix all those things when the OP wants to extract all roots in the `Range[0.001,1.,0.001]` as stated in one of his/her comments.

Comment: Indeed. In this case I would subtract a small number of the lower bound for each computation. But probably this fix is specific to this function. I wouldn't know what to do in a general situation.

Comment: @fcpenha Thanks a lot for your answer, it indeed solved my problem :).

Comment: @halirutan When I run the code for that specific value of 0.1, I see that there is a problem. But fortunately when I run the code for all my interval, there wasn't any void! The thing is that there are two parameters in xi==m1*R, and when I make my table with respect tp these two parameters, I don't have that problem. Thanks a lot by the way.

Answer (score 6):

I see two potential pitfalls in your approach. First, you need to understand that `FindRoot` is a numerical procedure which starts at a certain point and tries to find a root by approximating the gradient and moving towards it$^{1}$. Therefore, different starting points might lead to different roots, although you probably would expect they give the same root.

Therefore, it can happen if you choose the start point badly, you end up with a completely unexpected root since maybe the gradient was too large and introduced a very big first step:

```
FindRoot[x - 0.25 Pi*Cot[Pi*x] == 0, {x, 4.99}]
(* {x -> 2.11326} *)
```

Second, when you are completely out of luck, then it might happen you choose a starting point which is a singularity. Although you get a warning, you might over-read this and use this wrong root:

```
FindRoot[x - 0.25 Pi*Cot[Pi*x] == 0, {x, 5.0}]
(* {x -> 5.} *)
```

This is why I suggest for your example a different approach. You could extract *all* roots in a certain interval and delete those, which are singularities. This is in your case easy, because you used `Cot` and the singularities are the roots where `Sin[Pi x]` is zero. After you collected all roots, you can use `Nearest` to create a function which indeed gives always the nearest root to your input:

```
With[{roots = 
   Quiet[Select[
     Union[x /. (FindRoot[x - 0.25 Pi*Cot[Pi*x] == 0, {x, #1}] & /@ 
         Range[0.1, 10, .1])], Abs[Sin[Pi #]] > 10.0^-5 &]]},
 giveRootAt[x_?NumericQ] := First[Nearest[roots, x]]
]
```

A quick check reveals that you get the correct roots now:

```
{#,giveRootAt[#]}&/@Range[.5,5.5]
(* 
  {{0.5,0.362393},{1.5,1.18617},{2.5,2.11326},
  {3.5,3.07949},{4.5,4.06081},{5.5,5.04912}}
*)
```

Footnote 1: This is not entirely correct. `FindRoot` has several modes and options where you can influence the behavior. See the [reference page for more information](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindRoot.html?q=FindRoot&lang=en).

### Update regarding your comment

Beware that for very small $\xi$ it's getting harder to extract the roots reliably. Therefore, I will work with a minimal $\xi$ of 0.1. What you can do is to use the above method and create several `giveRootAt` functions. I will give for illustration purposes a slightly different version which defines several `giveAllRoots` function but the definition of `giveRootAt` is equivalent. The main difference in the code below is, that the whole definition is now a `Function` which takes $\xi$ as parameter. With this, we can map it over the list of $\xi$ values you want:

```
Function[xi,
  With[{roots = 
    Quiet[x /. (FindRoot[x - xi*Pi*Cot[Pi*x] == 0, {x, #}] & /@ Range[0.1, 20, xi/2])]},
    giveAllRoots[xi] = Select[Union[roots], Chop[Sin[Pi #]] != 0 &]
  ]
] /@ Range[0.1, 1.0, 0.001];
```

Now you have a function for which gives you the roots for different values of $\xi$ ranging from 0.1 to 1.0 in 0.001 steps.

To test this you can use for instance a `Manipulate` showing you the roots

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[x - \[Xi]*Pi*Cot[Pi*x], {x, 0, xmax}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, Point[{#, 0}] & /@ giveAllRoots[\[Xi]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-3, 3}}],
 {xmax, 2, 20},
 {\[Xi], 0.1, 1.0, 0.001}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It solves the problem for only one value of ξ. What I did before was that I made a table with respect to ξ, and I used `Map` to put `FindRoot` in each element of the table:

    table=Table[{ξ,x-ξ*Pi*Cot[Pi*x]},{ξ,0.001,1.,0.001}];
    final =table /. {{a_,c_} :> {a, 
    FindRoot[c, {x,0.5}]};

This gives me all λ_0s for different values of ξ. Then I used a `For` loop to find other λs, putting `FindRoot[c, {x,0.5+i}]}`, i changing form 0 to 20. How can I do all these things using your method?

Comment: @ZKT Please see my update in the answer.

Comment: Dear @halirutan , thanks a lot for the time you put to answer my question. Your method was useful, but since I need to consider very small values of xi in my code (as they are physical parameters and I can't just ignore them), so NSolve works better in my case. Thanks again by the way :).

Comment: @ZKT Please, then *don't* accept my answer as final solution. fcpenha's solution is nice and small and if it solves your problem, you really should keep this as accepted answer. If you like my answer, upvote it, but accept the one the solves your problem.

Comment: Did as you said. I learnt things from your answer by the way :)...